# How to show the only part of the image

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs, react-native

**UPDATE** Since the question was complicating and unclear, I'm rewriting my question to make it much simpler.

[image]

**Given**

- image (image uri for entire image; 600x600 image from the example)
- left(x-coordinate; 50 from the example)
- top(y-coordinate; 100 from the example)
- width(width of the image; 300 from the example)
- height (height of the image; 300 from the example)

**what I want**

- 300 x 300 image (which is cropped to the image)
- 70 x 70 image (I will ultimately resized image to 70 x 70 size)

Here is my example code

```
// render the part of the image
console.log(left); // 50
console.log(thumbSize); // 300
return (
        <Image
          source={{uri: image}}
          style={selectedStyle(left, top, thumbSize)}/>
      );
... 
function selectedStyle(left, top, thumbSize) {
  return {
    left,
    top,
    width: thumbSize,
    height: thumbSize
  };
}
```

**UPDATE** from zvona's working demo, what I want is this.

[image] but nothing else.

[image]

Comment: I guess this is very difficult question

Comment: If you have tagging in place and you can't get your pinch working properly you need to proportionally resize image width and height to tag area width, height, top and left. I am not entirely sure what is your problem, sorry.

Comment: @Andrei Resizing is working. I think I explained too much for simple question. I'm editing my question. I will let you know soon

Comment: Dear @Andrei, I just edited whole question for you. let me know if anything is unclear :) Thanks

Comment: @Andrei This problem is solved and this is continuous problem if you are interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435261/showing-the-part-of-image-with-fixed-width-and-height

Comment: Upvoting because of your great illustrations :)

Comment: @P.MyerNore thanks! :) glad you like it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/cropped-image

The idea is to have "cropped" `View` where `Image` is positioned inside it with custom dimensions. I use constants in my example to clarify the case.

```
<View style={styles.cropped}>
  <Image
    style={styles.image}
    source={{uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png'}} />
</View>
```

And on styles:

```
  image: {
    marginLeft: -OFFSET_LEFT,
    marginTop: -OFFSET_TOP,
    width: IMAGE_WIDTH,
    height: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
  },

  cropped: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: OFFSET_LEFT,
    top: OFFSET_TOP,
  },
```

Note that `ImageBackground` is only for example purposes and it's not needed in the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I didn't mean to ask about how to show cropped image. Rather than drawing square from the image (using ImageBackground. It's already working!!), I want to get only the part of the image as I described it on my example image.

Comment: As I specified, "what I want" is not whole image but 300 x 300 image which is already cropped (that's why I provided coordinates, width/height).

Comment: You implemented the example at the left picture. But "what I want" is the right one. I'm sorry.

Comment: Hmm.. Then I have to be honest that I don't understand your question.

Comment: ok. maybe my question was unclear. I added another sketch explaining my problem. From you demo, whole image except the square (300 x 300) part was blurred out(as blue). BUT I don't want to see the rest of image but only the SPECIFIC portion from the image.

Comment: I added simpson image on my question. please check it out. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: The rest of the image was only a proof that it gets cropped correctly. You can ignore that part and only focus on the View and Image parts of the code.

Comment: My bad :) Can we resize the cropped image (300 x 300) to (75 x 75)?

Comment: what is 239 and 391 for IMAGE_WIDTH and IMAGE_HEIGHT ??

Comment: 239 / 391 is just the dimensions of that particular Homer image. You just change the dimensions according to your image(s). So 600 / 600 in this case. And same goes with 150 / 150 about the cropped area size.

Comment: How do we resize the cropped image? While maintaining cropped image, I want to make the cropped image smaller.

Comment: Hi! This is continuous problem from this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435261/showing-the-part-of-image-with-fixed-width-and-height

Comment: why are you multiplying by 1.5?

Comment: I have a follow up question utilizing your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand here. You want to show only part of an image(x: 50, y:10, width: 300, height 300) and then resize this part to 70x70, right?
So 70x70 is the size of the final container.
First calculate the the x and y coords. with respect to the final size

```
var ar = 70 / 300
var x = 50 * ar
var y = 100 * ar
```

Then the width in percent:

```
var pc = (600 / 300) * 100
```

Assuming you show the cropped and resized image as a div background you do like this:

```
div.style.background = 'no-repeat ' + -x + 'px' + ' ' + -y + 'px/' + pc + '% url("' + imgAbsPath + '")'
```